# Select first record after change in group of records in a set

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to select first record after change in value in a set. In below data on change in Type wanted to pick first record with Type 'P'
for eg data is:

```
id  startdate   enddate   Type  status
123 1/01/2021   5/05/2021   C   A
123 6/05/2021   30/06/2021  C   A
123 1/07/2021   30/08/2021  P   A
123 31/08/2021  31/12/2021  P   A
```

Required Output :

```
123 1/07/2021   30/08/2021  P   A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condider this :

```sql
 SELECT * EXCEPT(start_dt)
   FROM sample, UNNEST([PARSE_DATE('%e/%m/%Y', startdate)]) start_dt
QUALIFY IFNULL(LAG(Type) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_dt), Type) <> Type
  ORDER BY start_dt
  LIMIT 1;
```

output:

[image]